# Python 3: The visibility of global variables across modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, global-variables

Similar questions have been asked before:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990556/python-how-to-make-global-imports-from-a-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084977/python-how-can-i-import-all-variables) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/python-visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules), and I am aware of these.

Say you have 2 modules where one has global variables that you want to read from in another module. Is there a way to make these accessible across modules without having to refer to them as module.variable each time?

Example:

modulea.py:

```
import moduleb
from moduleb import *

print("A String: " + astring)
print("Module B: " + moduleb.astring)
afunction()
print("A String: " + astring)
print("Module B: " + moduleb.astring)
```

moduleb.py:

```
astring = "dlroW olleH"

def afunction():
    global astring
    astring = "Hello World"
```

The output is

```
A String: dlroW olleH
Module B: dlroW olleH
A String: dlroW olleH
Module B: Hello World
```

suggesting that by using "from module import * " the global variables are copied rather than referenced.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`from module import *` binds the objects in `module` to like named variables in the current module. This is not a copy, but the addition of a reference to the same object. Both modules will see the same object until one of them rebinds the object. Modifying a mutable object doesn't rebind the variable so an action such as appending to a list is okay. But reassigning the the variable does rebind it. Usually the rebind is straight forward:

```
myvar = something_else
```

But sometimes its not so clear

```
myvar += 1
```

For immutable objects such as `int` or `str`, this rebinds the variable and now the two modules have different values.

If you want to make sure you always reference the same object, keep the namespace reference.