# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapplication'

Tags: python, fastapi

I am getting a module not found error in a fastapi project even thought the path is correct, the files are as follows

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from myapplication.app.database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String(255))
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
```

> File "Projects\FastApiStructure\myapplication.\users\models.py", line 4, in 
> from myapplication.app.database import Base
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapplication'

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from app.core.config import settings

engine = create_engine(settings.DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


@as_declarative()
class Base:

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__.lower()
```

my folder structure is as follows

[image: folder structure]

Comment: Where do you think you have a module called `myapplication`?

Comment: myapplication is the parent of app folder

Comment: from app.database import Base worked

Comment: See related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 0):

To consider `myapplication` as a module there should be a `__init__.py` file in that directory.
Based on your project structure, you could put the import statement as below using relative positioning:

```py
from ..app.database import Base
```