# Python: importing from beyond top level

Tags: python, import, fastapi

I have a Python FastAPI project with two applications that can be run separately or at the same time. The structure is like this:

```
project/
  app_1/
    models/
      model_1.py
    file_1.py
    app_1.Dockerfile
  app_2/
    models/
      model_1.py
    file_1.py
    app_2.Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yaml
```

These applications/API's share some of the models and to avoid maintaining the same models in multiple locations, I'd like to move all models under the `project/` -folder and import them from there.

If I want to import something from `project/models/model_1.py` in `project/app_2/file_1.py`, how can I do it?
I've tried importing it `from project.models.model_1 import Model` but I get an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`.
I also tried using dots like this: `from ........project.models.model_1 import Model` (Note: my real structure is more complicated than the example I've provided and that would be the real amount of dots to get to the top level). This gives me an error: `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

Is it possible at all to do what I'm trying to do? If yes, how could I achieve it?

Comment: if it's more complicated than the example above, then consider looking at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/. also note that there ain't any `__init__.py` in your structure example therefore no modules. `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` probably means that you have too many dots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when trying to unpickle a model in Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303417/modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-unpickle-a-model-in-flask-app)

Comment: Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804).

Comment: Thank you @aleksandarbos and @Chris , I will look on to those answers. Should the `project/` -folder also be a python package?