# FastAPI fails to import azure.communication - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.communication'

Tags: azure, fastapi

This line of code gives the following error dump:

from azure.communication.email import EmailClient

> INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to
> quit) INFO:     Started reloader process [10036] using WatchFiles
> Process SpawnProcess-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314,
> in _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108,
> in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn_subprocess.py",
> line 76, in subprocess_started
> target(sockets=sockets)   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line
> 61, in run
> return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
> return runner.run(main)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
> return self.*loop.run_until_complete(task)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in
> run_until_complete
> return future.result()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line
> 68, in serve
> config.load()   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line
> 473, in load
> self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py",
> line 24, in import_from_string
> raise exc from None   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py",
> line 21, in import_from_string
> module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\sofia\miniconda3\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 126, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 1176, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 690, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 940, in
> exec_module   File "", line 241, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\sofia\sources\MaddieBioGenetics\AzCommServicesApi\app.py",
> line 3, in 
> from azure.communication.email import EmailClient ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.communication'

If I put the same code in a simple python test app it works fine. Environment is Win11 Pro, Python 3.11.4, FastApi the latest version.

Any idea why FastApi fails to find the azure-communication-email library? I've been installing and upgrading it several times. Thank you!

Comment: could you please the code you tried

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804)

Comment: The code to test is very simple, just one line: from azure.communication.email import EmailClient.  FastApi seems to have trouble import the Azure.communication module. If I use a main() function to run it as a standalong app then it works fine.

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug in fastapi or azure.communication package. anyways, I dropped fastapi back to 0.97.0 and was able to get it working.

Comment: @David Mai, please look into the links which  Chris provided